# Doctrine Timestampable extension not persisting

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-2.1

I have Doctrine timestampable set for my symfony doctrine and other entities are handling this as they should but one is not not setting any date at all.

```
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
    use Digital\UserBundle\Entity\User;

    /**
     * ChallengeScore
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="app_challenges_scores")
     * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
     * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
     * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"race" = "Digital\ApplicationBundle\Entity\Race\ChallengeScore", "individual" = "ChallengeScore"})
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Digital\ApplicationBundle\EntityRepository\ChallengeScoreRepository")
     */
    class ChallengeScore


    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_added", type="datetime")
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     */
    private $date_added;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_modified", type="datetime")
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     */
    private $date_modified;


    /**
     * Set date_added
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateAdded
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setDateAdded($dateAdded)
    {
        $this->date_added = $dateAdded;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * Get date_added
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDateAdded()
    {
        return $this->date_added;
    }


    /**
     * Set date_modified
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateModified
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setDateModified($dateModified)
    {
        $this->date_modified = $dateModified;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * Get date_modified
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDateModified()
    {
        return $this->date_modified;
    }
}
```

I was thinking maybe there is an issue with this configuration having inheritance defined... Can anyone spot a problem?

No errors just 00000 persisted to db (so nothing)

Comment: I would recommend you var_dump your date in your setter method and make sure it is being metabolized correctly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [`DoctrineExtensions`](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/timestampable.md) example

You can see that there are no `setters` for the `timestampable` members, so just delete `setDateAdded()` and `setDateModified()` methods

Answer (score 29):

Don't forget to add the following to your app/config/services.yml:

```
services:
    gedmo.listener.timestampable:
        class: Gedmo\Timestampable\TimestampableListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
        calls:
            - [ setAnnotationReader, [ '@annotation_reader' ] ]
```

What this basically does is it "listens" if an event is triggered to update/create an entity in your database and it will set the dates.

I hope this solved the problem.

Comment: It was not obvious a bit but documentation about it are not in the main Timestampable article but it's here https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/doc/symfony4.md

Answer (score 1):

I removed the setters from entity class and add the below code into `services.yml`:

```
gedmo.listener.timestampable:
    class: Gedmo\Timestampable\TimestampableListener
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
    calls:
        - [ setAnnotationReader, [ @annotation_reader ] ].
```

It's working fine for me.